# Animated show where characters had crystals on their bodies that gave powers

Tags: story-identification, animation

i am looking for a show that i have vaguely in my memories so I dont remember much about it
but what i remember is:

- the characters had crystals or something similar on their bodies
- said crystals gave them some kind of powers i think it could range from changing their body to
  giving them powers (this part might be wrong but i am sure there were psychic powers)
- it had that dated military style of changing locations where whenever they went to a place it
  had green text with the time and location on it.
- I think it had a serious mood
- the only other thing i remember about it is I think it came out around the same time as code
  lyoko because i watched them at around the same time

sorry that is all I remember about it i hope someone finds the name of it, thanks for reading

Comment: Hi, welcome to SF&F.  When and where did you watch this?

Comment: 3D animation? Traditional animation? Flash cartoon?

Comment: I think i watched it on a roku on Netflix from 2010-2013 and it was as far as i remember mostly 2d or 3d animation, i think the style is comparable to young justice

Comment: If someone posts the correct answer, you can accept by clicking on the checkmark by the voting buttons, as per the [tour].

Comment: I've closed your question as a duplicate, but that doesn't mean it was a bad question, just one that we've had before.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suspect you may be looking for the animated adaptation of *[The 99](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_99)*

> The 99 are ordinary teenagers and adults from across the globe, who come into possession of one of the ninety-nine magical mystical Noor Stones (Ahjar Al Noor, Stones of Light) and find themselves empowered in a specific manner. All dilemmas faced by The 99 are overcome through the combined powers and capabilities of three or more members. Through this, The 99 series aims to promote values such as cooperation and unity throughout the Islamic world. Although the series is not religious, it aims to communicate Islamic virtues which are, as viewed by series creator Dr. Al-Mutawa, universal in nature.

### Opening of scene with teletype showing location and time

[image]

Comment: yea this is it i just watched the opening scene and i remember it your amazing thank you